# Choose the best combination of 5 stocks from 15 stocks using PCA

Tags: portfolio-optimization, pca, eigenvalue

I am working on a project to choose the perfect combination of 5 stocks from a total of 15 stocks to get the "highest gains". Here's the approach I plan to use.
Run a loop for all combinations of 5 stocks from 15 (i.e. 15C5). Once I have the eigenvalues for each combination, I have learnt that the portfolio with the largest first eigenvalues often have the highest variance/risk.
Then would the right approach be to choose the portfolio with the lowest first eigenvalue?

Or is there an better indicator I should be looking at? Or perhaps I shouldn't look at only the first eigenvalue for each combination, but at the other ones as well?

Feel free to point to any resources that might help.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, I think you need to clarify some of the aspects here: What does "highest gains" mean? Do you want to obtain the highest expected portfolio return? Do you want to maximize the sharpe ratio of said portfolio (risk vs return)? Do you want to minimize the portfolio's variance? In your case, I would into mixed continuous/binary programming techniques; you could also take some shortcuts and do a LASSO portfolio optimization - and increase the LASSO penalty until you have selected exactly 5 assets.

Comment: You may also like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64020542/how-to-do-portfolio-optimization-with-constraints-on-the-number-of-assets

Comment: Yet another suggestion: 15C5=3003 - You could simply do those 3003 portfolio selections and chose the 'optimum'.Quick & Dirty; your boss will like it. But that does not scale well to larger combinatorial problems.

Comment: Your suggestions were very helpful, thanks!